# Percentage of decisive games decided by tactical mistakes?

Tags: tactics, statistics

In their book, *The Woodpecker Method*, Axel Smith and Hans Tikkanen give these percentages of decisive games decided by tactical mistakes:

> GMs 42%
> 2200-2400 44%
> 2000-2200 63%
> 1800-2000 72%

They say:

> The percentages in the three rating bands below GM level are based on 32 randomly chosen games in each category

"32 randomly chosen games in each category" seems a rather small sample size for determining this information. Does anybody have more comprehensive results based on (much) larger sample sizes?

As I dipped below 1800 a few years ago, I would also be interested in the 1600-1800 category.